# Assigning array name to a variable and sorting in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Absolute RoR newbie here, I'm trying to render out multiple leagues in a loop, incrementing the div_# each time, here's a cut down version, without the html. It works when I hard code div_1 or div_2 to be sorted, but div_name doesn't work, even though it has the right contents I need it to be seen as the array.

```
<%  div_1 = Array.new
    div_1 << { :Name => 'Rob', :Played => '2', :Won => '1', :Lost => 1, :Points => 4}

    div_2 = Array.new
    div_2 << { :Name => 'Gavin', :Played => '2', :Won => '1', :Lost => 1, :Points => 4}

    for i in (1..2) 

    i = i.to_s
    div_name = "div_" + i 

    div_name.sort_by { |position| position[:Points] }.reverse!.each do |position| %>

<%= position[:Name] %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of problems here:

```
div_1 = Array.new
div_1 << { :Name => 'Rob', :Played => '2', :Won => '1', :Lost => 1, :Points => 4}
```

`div_1` is now an array with a single element, which is a hash. You don't need an array if you'll just have one element in it.

```
for i in (1..2)
```

Where's the block for this loop? After that statement, `i` is still undefined, so when you call

```
i = i.to_s
```

you'll get a NameError.

```
div_name = "div_" + i
```

Even if `i == 1`, `div_name` will be a string with value 'div_1', and not a copy or instance of the `div_1` variable you define above.

```
div_name.sort_by { |position| position[:Points] }.reverse!.each do |position| %>
```

Now you're trying to call `sort_by` on a string, which doesn't respond to that, because it doesn't make sense.

```
<%= position[:Name] %>
```

You don't have a variable named `position` defined at this scope.

Also, when you find yourself putting lots of logic inside of a view within `<% %>` tags, that's a sign that you need to move that code elsewhere, like to the controller. You could define and calculate `@positions` as an array of hashes in the controller, and then in the view do something like:

```
<% @positions.each do |position| %>
  <%= position[:name] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the guidance, seems like I need it.

I'll definitely have more elements in, I just cut it down as an example, the blocks should indeed have end's at the bottom of what I provided.

I will be moving things into the controller when I get it working, just wanted to do one step at a time to get my head around these things. 

Strangely the i = i.to_s part worked, I didn't get any errors, and I can print the value with no problems.

My final goal is to have all the leagues iterated over by a loop and create individual, sorted tables.